# how can i detect date from UITextView and add an event as you tap it

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview

Can i detect date from `UITextView` and add an event as you tap it. 
The text view is not in editable mode. 
I tried

```
self.txtView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
```

but its not working please help me

Comment: put your relevant code ?

Comment: Do you want to get the `UITextView`'s text?????

Comment: yes i want to get only date from UITextView

Answer (score 0):

What hypothetical dates are you typing in your application? If they are in the past it won't detect them.

The dates must be future dates.

Also, it's not about whether there is a tap gesture recognizer or not. You just have to make sure it's not in editable mode, however you do that.

My solution just toggles editing mode and `dataDetectorTypes` to `All` or `None` as appropriate via a button. You can set yours to just `UIDataDetectorTypeCalenderEvent` if you like.

For Example:

```
- (IBAction)didTapEditButton:(id)sender {

    if (self.noteText.editable == NO) {

        [self.editButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.noteText.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone;
        self.noteText.editable = YES;

    } else {

        [self.editButton setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.noteText.editable = NO;
        self.noteText.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add `UITapGestureRecogniser` in this way..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
      [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(doSingleTap)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1; 
    [self.txtView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

}
-(void)doSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    // ----- do here........
}
```